# CSS Container DIV Not Expanding

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've been researching this for hours now and it seems to be an IE thing but my issue is that I have a container DIV that, in IE9, doesn't expand and cuts everything off after about 400px. Chrome and FF work perfectly, of course.

**Container DIV**

```
#main_container{
font-family: arial, verdana;
width: 920px;
top: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #fff;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Page Container DIV**

```
#page_container{
font-family: arial, verdana;
font-size: 14px;
width: 900px;
color: #000;
border: 0px solid;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the standard markup of page block looks like this

```
<div id="main_container">
  <div id="page_container">
    Variable page data goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an issue with my CSS that I'm missing or is there an IE hack that I need to apply?

**UPDATED SCREENSHOTS**

IE9
[image: Here is IE 9]

Chrome / FF
[image: Here is Chrome and FF]

Comment: Is any of your `Variable page data` floated or positioned absolutely?

Comment: No floats, all static HTML data or pulled dynamically from a database.

Comment: Maybe you could post a jsfiddle demonstrating your bug? Because I don't see any problems in the code above.

Comment: Try giving `#main_container, #page_container { position: relative; float: none; height: auto;}`

Answer (score 0):

The cut off could be coming from the 'overflow: hidden' in '#page_container'.

Did you try `overflow: auto` ?

Comment: No luck, I tried overflow: auto and taking out overflow completely. Wouldn't that affect FF and Chrome as well? Those two browsers work fine.

Comment: @rsmith84 cut off happens vertically of horizontally?

Comment: Yes, but normally `overflow: hidden` just says preserve the width/height of the `<div>` and if the content internally is larger, just hide it. If you want it to expand you shouldn't use `overflow: hidden`. Is there any other CSS that could be effecting it? Did you try giving the `<div>` an explicit height just to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I tried using min-height: 700px !important but that didn't do anything. Added screenshots to OP

Comment: Can you try something else, in case its not related to that. `html { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the advice and help, greatly appreciated. Saved a few hairs!

@crowjonah's solution of

> Try giving #main_container, #page_container { position: relative; float: none; height: auto;} – crowjonah 2 mins ago

Solved the problem.

Comment: You should mark this answer (or ask @crowjonah to post his) as correct.